# How do I get the a save to Excel dialog box to pop up?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, dom-events, savefiledialog

I have the following script. It exports my data as .xls. I want a save dialog box to popup when this window opens. How can I accomplish this?

```
function ExporttoExcel() {
var sOption = "toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,";
sOption += "scrollbars=yes,width=750,height=600,left=100,top=25";

var sWinHTML = document.getElementById('contentstart').innerHTML;

var winprint = window.open("", "", sOption);
winprint.document.open();
winprint.document.write('<html><head>')

winprint.document.write('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel">')
winprint.document.write('<meta http-equiv="Content-disposition": attachment; filename="file.xls">')
winprint.document.write('</head><body>')

winprint.document.write(sWinHTML);
winprint.document.write('</body></html>');
winprint.document.close();
winprint.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find much inspiration on this SO thread : [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)

And on this other thread too : [How to download csv file using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183110/how-to-download-csv-file-using-jquery)

Let us know what you have tried and if you had troubles.